# Converting language type to string in R using infix notation

Tags: r, string, infix-notation

Let's say that I have the following expression in R:

```
someExpr <- substitute(a+2*b)
```

Now I want to look at a subexpression of this, let's say `2*b` and generate the string `"2*b"`. I access the subexpression with:

```
someExpr[[3]]
2 * b
```

And the type is language and the class is `call`

```
typeof(someExpr[[3]])
[1] "language"
```

I tried to convert this naively with `toString` and `as.character`, but then I always get the prefix order:

```
toString(someExpr[[3]])
[1] "*, 2, b"
as.character(someExpr[[3]])
[1] "*" "2" "b"
```

Is it possible to get the string in infix notation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `deparse` :

```
someExpr <- substitute(a+2*b)
result<-deparse(someExpr[[3]])
result
[1] "2 * b"

str(result)
chr "2 * b"
```

Comment: Great! Exactly what I need!